# Can the Behringer XR18 XAIR Digital Mixer be used as a breakout box?

Tags: recording, live-sound

I'm looking for ways to record 8 channels of sound to a DAW while passing the 8 channels along to the sound guy.  The Behringer XR18 has been reccommended to me but I don't want to buy it until I know it will work.

At this point reading manuals I can't figure out how to route 8 channels from the 8 inputs to 8 outputs for the sound guy while recording 8 channels to a laptop DAW through the USB. Is this even possible? I'd like to leave the sound guy completely responsible for FOH and unpowered wedge monitors at this point.

Comment: Does the mixer have 8 outputs on TRS or XLR jacks? Another way to do this is to get an 8 channel XLR splitter and then any interface you want.

Comment: @ToddWilcox it's got 6 aux outputs and main L R outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use the XR18 as a breakout box.  I just got some info from a live sound engineer.

All the XR18 sockets except for power are on the front face.
[image]

Use a mixer app like [Mixing Station X Air Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.davidgiga1993.mixingstation.xairpro).

The routing for each XLR output "Aux 1-6 and Main L-R" contains an option for Source and a drop down menu something like:

1. Input
2. Pre-EQ
3. Post-EQ
4. Pre-Fader
5. Post-Fader

To send a channel signal through (just like a DI box):

- Use the Output channels  Aux 1-6 and Main L-R
- For each input channel 1 and each output channel, for example 1: in Aux 1, select Channel 1 for source, and select Input from the drop
  down, thus grabbing the line in audio on that channel before any
  further processing or sends to recording.
- Then assign Channel 1 to USB channel 1 for recording that channel on your DAW on the laptop.
- Then configure your DAW to accept the USB channel. My DAW is going to be [Reaper](http://reaper.fm/)

Answer (score 2):

Open IO properties in XairEdit, select the tab 1-18 ch, reset the USB Sends and Returns. Download the Asio driver for PC and install. Plug in usb cable (printer cable) to connect both PC and XR18. Open DAW and go to Preferences or Settings, in audio section select Asio Xr18. For each Track assign an Input channel-Track 1 for input ch1 from mixer. Arm the track (rec button in the track itself). You should see activity from ch1. I'm using Tracks Live and tracktion t7 as DAW.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but maybe others might benefit.
The XR18 can send 6 AUX returns and 2 stereo outs.
So in theory, you could route all 8 tracks to 8 outputs while have it record everything too (all 8 tracks).
Not sure if this is the most handy solution, but it could work.